# Shiny dashboard. Hide checkboxes but retain their default value

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shinydashboard that I hope to use as a template across several projects. In the side panel I have filters so the user can create a subset of the data, eg gender. I wish to be able to hide certain filters on some projects but still have the output to pass to functions.

For example in ui.r I have

```
uiOutput("genderGroup")
```

which I need hiding from view in the dashboard.

In server.r I have

```
output$genderGroup <- renderUI({
checkboxGroupInput("genderFilter",label=h5("Filter by Gender"),
                    choices  =c("Male"= 1, "Female"= 2),
                    selected =c(1, 2)
                    )
})
```

I still need to capture the output from the genderGroup checkboxes as several reactive functions require the filter as an argument. I've tried hiding the uiOutput with hidden(uiOutput("genderGroup")) in ui.r but the dashboard hangs when trying to look for the value for output$genderFilter.

Note: I'm using the dashboard as a template. I do not want to rewrite functions excluding certain filters on a project by project basis. As data across all projects will contain the same filtered fields, I just want to go in and hide those filters that the project does not need for subsetting. When hidden, the default selected values will be passed to the function.

Thanks

Andrew